# How to find the particular solution of the initial value problem (ODE)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $xy'+ y = 1984x^{1983}$
>
> $y(1) = 1985$.

**My Work:**

$xy'(x) + y = 1984x^{1983}$

Then subtract $x$ from both sides and divide both sides by $x$ to get:

$y'(x) = 1984x^{1982} - \frac{y}{x}$

Where do I go from here? How do I get only $x$'s on the right side, and only $y$'s on the left? So that I could properly integrate? I'm having issues with the  $-y\over x$ part. What should I do?

Comment: Particula Sol$\displaystyle\dots = x^{1983}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hint***

$$xy'+y=1984x^{1983}$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(xy)'=(x^{1984})'$$
Integrate both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for first order:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + f(x)y = Q(x)$$

Solution for above D.E is:

$$y(IF) = \int Q(x)IF.dx + c$$

Where $$IF = e^{\int f(x)dx}$$

Now, converting your equation to above form:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x} = 1984x^{1982}$$

$$\Rightarrow IF = e^{\int\frac{1}{x}dx} = e^{lnx} = x \rightarrow(\because \int\frac{1}{x}.dx = lnx;\ e^{lnx} = x)$$
$$\Rightarrow y.x = \int 1984x^{1982}.x.dx + c$$
$$\Rightarrow y.x = x^{1984} + c$$

Now apply your boundary condition.

Remember, Leibniz rule for first order becomes handy for many first order equations of the form given above.